# Why is only half of the desktop appearing on the screen?

Tags: windows, display

This monitor was working normally until about a week ago.  I disconnected it from one PC, where it was working fine, and connected it to another.  Now the image on the screen is shifted to the right and off of the screen.  Here is a picture of the screen alongside a laptop that is sending the image as a second screen by VGA.

[image: Broken Screen?]

There also seems to be some discoloration to the green end of the spectrum.  Altering settings on the monitor does not change this.

**What I have tried:**

1. I have tried adjusting the settings on the monitor AND in the graphics settings.
2. The monitor has the same shifted image and discoloration in the BIOS.
3. I have checked the cables with multiple other screens and they work fine.
4. I have tried the monitor on other computers with different OSs and get the same result.
5. I have tried updating the graphics card(s).
6. I have searched for and installed drivers for this specific monitor (GNR TS700), although I never needed these in the past, but these make no difference.

Nothing I have tried has changed altered the problem.

Is this a broken screen?  Or is there anything else I could try?

Comment: Do you have another screen you can test with? Is the mouse cursor able to go all the way over to the left? Does it still occur if you extend the desktop rather than mirror it?

Comment: Have tired other screens, computers and cables.  The mouse will not go further than the visible image, no further over to the left than the desktop is displayed.  The same happens with extended, dual and single desktop.

Comment: So when using other screens you get the same green half display or do they display correctly?

Comment: No, with other screens I get a perfect image.

Comment: Does the OSD display correctly or is that shifted/green as well?

Comment: The monitor's menu displays correctly, in the center of the screen with no green shift.

Answer (score 2):

Seams like you have bent the connector pin carrying the red signal, and also the sync signal. Look at both sides of the connector.

Comment: This really should have been a comment not an answer as it is pure speculation.

Comment: "Why is only half the desktop on the screen?" ---> Because red carry sync signal and red is what lacks in the picture. This is either a connector fault or the red channel is broken on the monitor side.

Comment: @FrankSixteen I have just tried cleaning the connector on the monitor and checking for any debris that could be causing a fault.  The issue remains.

Comment: And pin number one is straight and the hole number one in the female connector at the screen side looks okay? Pin one is the upper right when you look into the cable holding it flat and the middle row pin is furthest to the right. http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/93078/soldering-a-vga-cable-number-of-wires-doesnt-match

Comment: Good explanation.  However, I have had a good look at the cables and the pins are not bent.  I have identified the number one pin hole and it seems fine.  I have cleaned it as best I can and the problem remains.

Comment: Then I'm afraid you got a faulty monitor. That's a good thing too. Now you know it needs a technician or a trip to the happy hunting grounds.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to correct this problem by removing the monitor from the multiple monitor configuration (Intel  HD Graphics Control panel - I suppose it can be also done directly in Windows) so that the operating system no longer could "see" the monitor. Afterwards, I re-added the external monitor which, I believe, re-set the configuration for the monitor and re-aligned the display.